# Checking if OneDrive is started before running script fails

Tags: batch, script, onedrive, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a bat script that checks if OneDrive is running, and if OneDrive is not running OneDrive.exe will be started.
I have 2 issues:
If OneDrive is running, it will close the cmd window after the message "proceeding script", it stops running the rest of the scripts
The other issue that if OneDrive is not running, it closes cmd window after the message "OneDrive is starting...", it again stops the running the rest of the script.
How can I resolve these 2 issues?

```
@echo off
set /p username="username: "
echo.
echo [33mChecking if OneDrive is running[0m
echo.
timeout 2 >nul

@echo off

Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq OneDrive" | find /I "OneDrive">nul && (
    
    echo [92mOneDrive is running[0m
    timeout 2 >nul
    echo.
)||(
    echo [91mOneDrive is not running![0m
    echo.
    echo [33mStarting OneDrive [0m
    start cmd.exe @cmd /c "runas /user:"driv\%username%" "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background"
    echo.
    echo OneDrive is started...
    Pause>nul
    timeout 1 >nul
    echo.
exit
)
@echo off

Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq OneDrive" | find /I "OneDrive">nul && (
    
    echo [33mProceeding script[0m
    timeout 2 >nul
    echo.
)||(
    echo [91m%OneDrive is not running![0m
    echo:
    echo [91mPlease reinstall OneDrive[0m
    timeout 1 >nul
exit
)

@echo off
timeout /T 3 /NOBREAK > nul
echo.
echo Please start robocopy
``
```

Comment: Why are you checking twice if it is running?

Comment: This seems to be simpler : `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq onedrive.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "onedrive.exe">NUL` and `if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" start "" %localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe`.

Comment: My question is how I can resolve the issue of my screen closing halfway the script

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo.
set "_status=running"
set /p "_username=username: " 

for /f %%E in ('prompt $E^&%ComSpec% /k ^<nul')do set "_$E=%%~E"

timeout 2 | echo;%_$E%[33mChecking if OneDrive is %_status%!.. %_$E%[0m

tasklist /fi "status eq running" | find /i "onedrive.exe" >nul && (
     set "_status=running"
     timeout 2 | echo; %_$E%[92mOneDrive is running!.. %_$E%[0m
    ) || (
     set "_status=not running"
     echo;%_$E%[91mOneDrive is !_status!^^!!.. %_$E%[0m
     echo;%_$E%[33mStarting OneDrive... %_$E%[0m
     start "" /b 2>&1 runas /user:"driv\%_username%" "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background" | find ":"
     timeout 3 >nul 
     tasklist /fi "status eq running" | find /i "onedrive.exe" >nul && (
          set "_status=started"
          echo;OneDrive is !_status!^^!!.. 
         )
    )
    
tasklist /fi "status eq running" | find /i "onedrive.exe" >nul && (
     timeout 2 | echo;%_$E%[33mProceeding script... %_$E%[0m
     goto :Proceeding
    ) || (
     set "_status=not started"
     echo;%_$E%[91mOneDrive is !_status!^^!!..  %_$E%[0m
     echo;%_$E%[91mPlease reinstall OneDrive!.. %_$E%[0m
    )

timeout 3 /nobreak | echo;Please start robocopy
endlocal & exit /b 

:Proceeding

  rem ::  Proceeding script from here
  rem ::  
  rem ::  ...
  rem ::  ...
  rem ::  ...
  rem ::

endlocal
```

---

Your question is a bit confusing for my English understanding (forgive my limitation), but I believe that the exits could be the reason for your problems.